# Shortcut to run all rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have to type

```
bundle exec rspec spec lib/crucible_kit/spec
```

every time I want to run all 700 of my rspec tests for my rails application. Is there anyway I could shorten down this to just typing "`rr`" to run all tests?
If so, where would I put this file in my rails application? And would I be able to push it to git branch so my teammates can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the code below in your command-line.

```
alias rr="bundle exec rspec"
```

It will be appended to this file `~/.bash_rc`

Comment: This is running 500 of my tests and not the last 200. How can I get it to run the entire command as I stated above? I tried alias rr= "bundle exec rspec spec lib/crucible_kit/spec" but that didn't work

Comment: You will have to to define a new alias rather than using 'rr'. Try what you've described in your comment again with a new alias

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can push this to git?

Comment: Yes! You can save it to GitHub. For my "dotfile" and add your ~/.bashrc file. https://github.com/Tr4pSt3R/dotfiles-1